# Blank page and TypeError Angular Firebase

Tags: angularjs, angular, firebase

I'm deploying my angular app to firebase and it isn't working. I compile using `ng build --prod --aot` and then deploy with `firebase init` and `firebase deploy` and it only shows a blank page with this error in the console:

```
ERROR TypeError: sg(...).auth is not a function
at main-es2015.0a35f570684f10de484e.js:1
at a.invoke (polyfills-es2015.5b10b8fd823b6392f1fd.js:1)
at s.run (polyfills-es2015.5b10b8fd823b6392f1fd.js:1)
at Kr.runOutsideAngular (main-es2015.0a35f570684f10de484e.js:1)
at new Sg (main-es2015.0a35f570684f10de484e.js:1)
at main-es2015.0a35f570684f10de484e.js:1
at xi (main-es2015.0a35f570684f10de484e.js:1)
at Ci (main-es2015.0a35f570684f10de484e.js:1)
at Bi.get (main-es2015.0a35f570684f10de484e.js:1)
at cr (main-es2015.0a35f570684f10de484e.js:1)
```

At first i thought it was of the version, i was using 5.14.1, so i downgraged to the 4.7.0 bc i saw someone saying that it worked for him but that's not my case, still not working.

Thank you for the help <3

Comment: When you run the prod build locally does it work? Check your `firebase.json` file to make sure it is has the correct path to your build output

Comment: could you share your code where you use this auth function?

Comment: Don't worry, i don't know how but i solve it hahaha i tried so many things so i don't really know what worked, i think it was the downgrade of the version i was using of firebase